# Accessing the extended (multi-line) Git commit message in Azure Pipeline YAML

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, appveyor

In AppVeyor we get the extended part of the Git commit message using the `APPVEYOR_REPO_COMMIT_MESSAGE_EXTENDED` [environment variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/), but I can't see an equivalent in Azure Pipelines.

If I create a `bash` step containing `printenv | sort` to view all the available environment variables in my YAML pipeline then the output indicates that the `BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE` only contains the first line of the commit message, and no `EXTENDED` equivalent exists. I can't see anything in the docs either. Our repo is hosted in GitHub rather than in Azure DevOps if this makes a difference.

Is possible to get the extended commit message in an Azure Pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked out an alternative way to get what I needed. The following line (in powershell) assigns the most recent commit message to `$commitMessageFull` as an array of strings, one string per line.

```
$commitMessageFull = git log -1 --pretty=%B
```

You can then split the first line and the extended message out with this:

```
$first, $extended = $commitMessageFull
```

The `$first` variable now contains a single string which is the first line of the commit message, and `$extended` contains an array of strings which is the remaining lines.